# how to call angularJS service into a controller that is not included in a controller?

Tags: angularjs

**how to call angularJS service into a controller that is not included in a controller?**

**productCtrl.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('productCtrl',['$scope','productService', function ($scope,campaignService) 
  {
      $scope.getLocations = function() {
      productService.getPorduct(response,status);
  }
}]);
```

**productService.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service('productService', ['ajaxService', function (ajaxService) {

this.getPorduct = function (successFunction, errorFunction) {

   ajaxService.AjaxGet("http:location.com/product#?clientid=10",    

successFunction, errorFunction);

  };
}]);
```

**ajaxService.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service('ajaxService', ['$http', 'blockUI', function ($http, blockUI) {

this.AjaxGet = function (route, successFunction, errorFunction) {
    blockUI.start();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: route }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            blockUI.stop();
            successFunction(response, status);
        }).error(function (response) {
            blockUI.stop();
            errorFunction(response);
        });
    }, 1000);

}

}]);
```

**When I access the controller to get the result from url, I am getting following error**
    `angular.js:13294 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'productCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: Yo, I'd think it's because you are continuously redefining your app. You are doing  var app = angular.module("myApp", []); on like 3 different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you should define angular `module` with same name should only created once per application & then utilize that module for extending component to it.

Here I can see three places where you have created module like

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

It should be created only once and then used like `angular.module("myApp")` where you wanted to add component to this module

`productService.js` & `ajaxService.js` should use module initially created module by `productCtrl.js`(assuming `productCtrl.js` loaded first). You need to change `productService.js` & `ajaxService.js` code from

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

---

Even better remove `var app = angular.module("myApp", []);` this line from other js file which are loaded later, then they will use `app` variable which is already loaded with `myApp` module

Comment: I just changed from `var app = angular.module("myApp", []); to `var app = angular.module("myApp");`  I am getting following error`   'angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: @SriChatala could you add your html, to see that how you are referring JS files on page.

Comment: I am using in a ASP.Net MVC applciation.

Comment: @SriChatala so what, you must be referring JS file on html page from somewhere, either directive reference on page **OR** having reference though bundle.

Comment: Now I am getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: blockUIProvider <- blockUI <- ajaxService <- campaignService` **FYI**: I am using `blockUI` service in ajaxService js file

Comment: @SriChatala and `blockUI` service I don't see anywhere in question..you mentioned about it..

Comment: I provided reference through bundle

Comment: Do you not just need to add a dependency on the blockUI into your module declaration? `var app = angular.module("myApp", ['blockUI'])`

Answer (score 1):

Only call the module with [] once, after that just use the module name.

```
// Creates the module
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

// call the same module from your other files
var app = angular.module("myApp"); // no []
```

[See the documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

In a nut shell with `[]` creates a new instance while without `[]` retrieves an existing/already created instance. Be sure your scripts are ordered so the first call is always with the `[]` parameter.